# Count down number in TextView on Button click

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` in a Game which counts the number of bullets in clip.
As the shoot button is pressed I want to subtract 1 from the number of bullets How can I do that ?

```
TextView rounds;

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        //What to do ?  
        break;
```

Comment: Why Down vote ? This is my 3rd account I don't want a ban !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768969/how-do-i-change-textview-value-inside-java-code & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613898/android-textview-value

Comment: You don't get banned for downvotes.

Comment: @Jean-Paul The Two questions are different and how should I find them !!! there title is totally different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read any basic Android tutorial. It'd save you and us a lot of time.

```
case R.id.button1: {
    int tmp = Integer.valueOf( rounds.getText().toString();
    rounds.setText( String.valueOf( tmp-1) );
}
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class game extends Activity{ //<- Change this (game)!

private int shoot=10;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game); //<- Change this!
     }

private void update(Button button){
    rounds.setText("Bullets"+ shoot--); //Update the information of the button
}

public void onClick(View button) { //When you click
    update((Button) button);  //Activates the update

}
```

Or you can also use:

```
TextView rounds;

public void onClick(View arg0) {

switch(arg0.getId()) {
case R.id.button1:
   rounds.setText("Bullets"+ shoot--);
   break;
}
```